# How to calculate time of mouse move?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

i have this code that discribe mouse move

```
import sys 
import math
import time
from datetime import datetime


from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from toolz.itertoolz import second

class Frame:
    def __init__(self, position, time):
        self.position = position
        self.time = time

    def speed(self, frame):
        d = distance(*self.position, *frame.position)
        time_delta = abs(frame.time - self.time)
        return d / time_delta
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    last_frame = get_current_frame()
```

i want calculate time when mouse was in move.
How i can set a timer that will do +1 second every time when mouse will be in move for a one second?

Comment: You'll have to rephrase this, I'm not sure what you're asking. If you just want to know information about mouse movement or button clicks, have you looked at the [QMouseEvent](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmouseevent.html) class?

Comment: i done it task) i just print time to log file, after i put it to set collection and take a len of set elements - it time of mouse move